Resetting steps via Foreground Service in the pedometer does not work
I'm writing a Pedometer in Java. I have a problem with ForegroundService. When you need to reset steps, they are not reset in the background, although everything works when the application is open.
A class with the service itself, which I later launch in the activity:
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("stats", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        stepCounterSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

        sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
                    float stepsAtMidnight = prefs.getFloat("stepsmidnight", 0);
                    float stepsToday = event.values[0] - stepsAtMidnight;

                    if (stepsToday >= 0) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putFloat("steps", stepsToday);
                        editor.putFloat("sensorSteps", event.values[0]);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };

        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, stepCounterSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        Notification notification = new Notification();
        startForeground(1, notification.createNotification());

        setMidnightResetAlarm(this);
    }

    public void setMidnightResetAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StepCounterResetReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 );
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (!alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
                Intent permissionIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM);
                startActivity(permissionIntent);
            }
        }


        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }

Accordingly, the service activation code is in the main activity:
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, StepCounterService.class);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);

